# Use ImageReader surface for video stream without Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, image-reader

I'm trying to get the video stream of a camera into an imagereader surface to be able to process these images. I found a lot of examples that deal with the camera2 API but I don't use that because my video stream comes from an external camera.

Ideally, I would have two surfaces: one as a preview and and one from the ImageReader to process the image. Similar to [this](https://github.com/halide/CVPR2015/blob/master/HoGCamera/src/com/example/hogcamera/Camera2BasicFragment.java). I understand that you combine the two surfaces with a `CaptureRequest.Builder` and then `.addTarget(surface)`. The problem is that I don't have a `CamerDevice` to make the `createCaptureRequest`.

The code I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/ruvu/android_sandbox/blob/master/LibraryDemo118/src/main/java/com/qihancloud/librarydemo/MediaControlActivity.java).

I tried to just create an ImageReader and its surface and pass it to the `startDecoding` function. But this didn't work quite well as I got this error:

```
E/JNI: close+++++++
E/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-1280x720f32315659m16-17834-0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/ACodec: NATIVE_WINDOW_MIN_UNDEQUEUED_BUFFERS query failed: No such device (19)
E/ACodec: Failed to allocate output port buffers after port reconfiguration: (-19)
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -19)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffed, actionCode 0, while in state 6
E/AccessHeadCameraActivity: Error has occured.
                            java.lang.IllegalStateException
                            at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
                            at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2379)
```

Any hint into the right direction would be nice!

**Update 1:**

The error results from the return value of `dequeueOutputBuffer`, as this has the value of `-1`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) on the MediaCodec, this means that the call timed out. But why does that happen?

**Update 2**

I don't have the `surfaceCreated` (because I don't have the SurfaceView anymore), so that code moved into the `onCreate`. Everthing else is pretty much the same as in [here](https://github.com/ruvu/android_sandbox/blob/master/LibraryDemo118/src/main/java/com/qihancloud/librarydemo/MediaControlActivity.java)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acess_headcamera);
    mediaManager = (MediaManager) getUnitManager(FuncConstant.MEDIA_MANAGER);

    setupImageReader();

    StreamOption streamOption = new StreamOption();
    streamOption.setChannel(StreamOption.MAIN_STREAM);
    streamOption.setDecodType(StreamOption.HARDWARE_DECODE);
    streamOption.setJustIframe(false);
    mediaManager.openStream(streamOption);

    surface = imageReader.getSurface();
    startDecoding(surface);

    initListener();
}

private void setupImageReader() {
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YV12,
            IMAGE_READER_BUFFER_SIZE);
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code how you do this?

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: @E.Abdel Have you had some time to look at the code? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the late rsponse, take a look at ImageReaderDecoderTest.java, it may be helpful for you https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ImageReaderDecoderTest.java